# Cookie collection used on different programming languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp-classic

I have problem with cookies collection used on different programming languages.

In the server is run Windows Server 2003 version .

In this server I have two websites: one is developed in **Classic ASP 3.0** and the other is developed in **ASP NET 4.0**

The two web applications use the cookie method to store user data who access the web.

If you log first on application developed in ASP NET 4.0 and after log on application developed in Classic ASP 3.0 I have error in line:

```
Response.Cookies("ClassicAsp_access")("User") = User
```

Then simply close the browser, delete cookies from the client and the access is restored.

What causes this behavior?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know that Server 2003 is now End of Life right? That means no new security patches will be released, even when new critical vulnerabilities are discovered. Even a fully-patched system will be vulnerable to attack. It's irresponsible to continue using this, and moving to a new system is job #1.

Comment: What is the error you get? And what sort of data is stored in `User`?